# Get the sum of particular values in a column via sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column with different values for absences -

**abs_table**

| absence_type | value | person_number | regular_measure_hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FLT | 8 | 10 | 90 |
| VAC | 9 | 10 |  |
| JUR | 1 | 10 |  |
| LOA | 6.5 | 10 |  |
| PAID | 2 | 10 |  |
| FLT | 10 | 1 | 80 |
| VAC | 9 | 1 |  |
| JUR | 10 | 1 |  |

***Query :***

```sql
SELECT WHEN absence_type IN ('FLT', 'JUR', 'BRV', 'LOD', 'PAID') THEN 
            regular_measure_hours 
            - SUM(VALUE) OVER (PARTITION BY person_number value 
                               ORDER BY person_number) 
        ELSE regular_measure_hours,
       person_number
  FROM abs_table
```

If the absence_type is in any of these- ('FLT','JUR','BRV','LOD','PAID')  then i need to subtract the sum of only those "Value" column with the regular_measure_hours

The sum over in the above column is not giving me the correct result in most cases.

***Desired output*** :

| person_number | regular_measure_hours |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 79 |
| 1 | 60 |

How can i tweak the sum over partition to get the right results

Comment: Do you really have a table exactly like `abs_table`, where `regular_measure_hours` has one non-null value per distinct person? That looks like an exceptionally flawed data model. Or do you in fact have the proper model (at least two tables; the "regular measure hours" stored in a separate, smaller table unrelated to "absences"), and what you are showing us is an intermediate result you computed in your attempt to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Group by the PERSON_NUMBER, and just for those 5 types.

```
SELECT
 PERSON_NUMBER, 
 SUM(regular_measure_hours)
 - SUM(CASE 
       WHEN Absence_type IN ('FLT','JUR','BRV','LOD','PAID')
       THEN VALUE
       ELSE 0
       END) as regular_measure_hours
FROM abs_table
WHERE (Absence_type IN ('FLT','JUR','BRV','LOD','PAID')
   OR regular_measure_hours IS NOT NULL) 
GROUP BY PERSON_NUMBER
ORDER BY PERSON_NUMBER
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need analytic `SUM()` function but conditional aggregation while taking `NVL()` into account in order to replace *NULL* values with *zero* such as

```sql
SELECT SUM(CASE
         WHEN absence_type IN ('FLT', 'JUR', 'BRV', 'LOD', 'PAID') THEN          
          NVL(regular_measure_hours,0) -NVL(value,0) 
       END) AS regular_measure_hours,
       person_number
  FROM abs_table
 GROUP BY person_number
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=298a94a5c739948b399517326d502cc8)</kbd>

Comment: The data model looks quite odd; for one thing, I don't believe we can assume that the "regular measure hours" value (the non-null value) appears in a row where the absence type is one of FLT, JUR etc. It may appear in a row with absence type VAC, for example (for an employee who only had VACation, no JURy duty etc.)

Comment: @mathguy  you're quite right indeed. We all depend on assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

With your single-table data model (assuming this is your real model), which is pretty absurd, you need an aggregation like this:

```
select person_number,
       sum(regular_measure_hours) -
         nvl(sum(case when absence_type in ('FLT', 'JUR', 'BRV', 'LOD', 'PAID') 
                      then value end), 0) as adjusted_hours
from   abs_table
group  by person_number
;
```